# What encoding am I using? $LANG doesn't have an encoding

Tags: character-encoding

It seems like typically:

```
echo $LANG
```

results in something like this:

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

What encoding is used when the result does not specify an encoding?

```
echo $LANG
en_US
```

How do I figure out what the default encoding is?

Using CentOS and Redhat (various versions).

Comment: Check the output of `locale charmap`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/locale.html).

Current encoding:

```
locale charmap
```

All available encoding:

```
locale -m
```

Example with my system:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8

$ LC_ALL=C export LC_ALL
$ locale charmap        
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```